# ListView from sqlite using CustomAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-custom-view

I am getting a problem while processing ArrayList value from List value of database
[image]

---

Basically I have two errors:

- Above shown one
- One from LogCat(`String resource ID #0x1`)

---

**CustomAdapter class** :

```
public class IncomeListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Income>{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
List<Income> incomeList;

public IncomeListAdaptor(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Income> objects) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.incomeList = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtId = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.idItem);
        holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dateItem);
        holder.txtAmount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.amountItem);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Income income = incomeList.get(position);
    holder.txtId.setText(income.getIncomeid());
    holder.txtAmount.setText(income.getAmount());
    holder.txtSource.setText(income.getSource());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtId;
    TextView txtAmount;
    TextView txtSource;

}}
```

**Database List Function**

```
        /**
     * getting all income
     * */

    public List<Income> getAllIncomes() {
        List<Income> incomes = new ArrayList<Income>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_INCOME;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Income in = new Income();
                in.setIncomeid(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INCOME_ID)));
                in.setAmount(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT)));
                in.setSource(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SOURCE)));
                in.setCdate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CDATE)));
                in.setPayementmode(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PAYEMENT_MODE)));

                // adding to income list
                incomes.add(in);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return incomes;
    }
```

**Fragment1.java class**

```
        mIncomeList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.incomelist);
    List<Income> values = db.getAllIncomes();
    IncomeListAdaptor adapter = new IncomeListAdaptor(getActivity(), R.layout.income_list_item_genrator, values);
    mIncomeList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**LogCat Error :**

```
    12-03 01:03:23.141: E/AndroidRuntime(17560): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 01:03:23.141: E/AndroidRuntime(17560): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
12-03 01:03:23.141: E/AndroidRuntime(17560):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
12-03 01:03:23.141: E/AndroidRuntime(17560):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2961)
12-03 01:03:23.141: E/AndroidRuntime(17560):    at parth.any.ttb.adapter.IncomeListAdaptor.getView(IncomeListAdaptor.java:53)
```

Comment: Well you constructor is expecting an `ArrayList` but you are giving it a `List` did you trying giving it an ArrayList instead?

Comment: Yes But by doing that i am still getting 2nd error of logCat as i explained..!!

Comment: where is line 53 in your adapter?

Comment: this one : holder.txtId.setText(income.getIncomeid());

Comment: why are you using `ViewHolder` ? you can simply use `row` to set text of your `textView` also check whether your `income.getIncomeid()` is returning something and as @tyczj said make `List<Income>` `ArrayList<Income>`.

Comment: post your income_list_item_generator.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
public IncomeListAdaptor(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Income> objects) {
```

to

```
public IncomeListAdaptor(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Income> objects) {
```

in your `IncomeListAdaptor` class.

**The Reason**

you are passing a `List` to a constructor that expects a `ArrayList`.
`ArrayList` is a one type of `List`. So you can't just have a `List` (which you don't know its *exact type*) and pass it to a method that expects the *exact type* `ArrayList`

**More accurate explanation**

`List` is an `interface` that has lots of implementors. One of these implementors is `ArrayList`. So, when a method expects a `ArrayList`, it is asking for a *specific* implementor not *any* implementor.

Answer (score 0):

And for the

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

error, make sure that the values you are trying to setText() to are actually String datatypes.

i.e in

```
holder.txtId.setText(income.getIncomeid());
holder.txtAmount.setText(income.getAmount());
holder.txtSource.setText(income.getSource());
```

makre sure that `income.getIncomeid()` and `income.getAmount()` and `income.getSource()` are actually Strings. If not convert them to Strings using appropriate methods such as `String.valueOf(income.getAmount());` etc